# Copy paste tables from word with multi-line cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have a word document that contains a number of tables. I've written a script to retrieve the tables starting at a specified table number i.e. table 1, 2, 3, or 4 and so on (user selects). The script then pulls the tables into an excel workbook. The problem I am having is that all of the tables have 4 columns. The 3rd column has content in it which contains multiple lines so when it pastes to excel, it looks bad. I understand that if you copy the 3rd column of any table, double click in a cell in excel and paste, it'll paste in the line breaks so it looks ok. Was wondering if there was a way to do this in vba.

Here is my table that I want to copy into Excel:

[image]

Here is what it looks like it when the script pastes it in:

[image]

Here is what I needed it to look like:

[image]

Here's what I have so far:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()

Dim wdDoc As Object
Dim wdFileName As Variant
Dim tableNo As Integer 'table number in Word
Dim iRow As Long 'row index in Excel
Dim iCol As Integer 'column index in Excel
Dim resultRow As Long
Dim tableStart As Integer
Dim tableTot As Integer

On Error Resume Next

ActiveSheet.Range("A:AZ").ClearContents

wdFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Word files (*.docx),*.docx", , _
"Browse for file containing table(s) to be imported")

If wdFileName = False Then Exit Sub '(user cancelled import file browser)

Set wdDoc = GetObject(wdFileName) 'open Word file

With wdDoc
    tableNo = wdDoc.Tables.Count
    tableTot = wdDoc.Tables.Count
    If tableNo = 0 Then
        MsgBox "This document contains no tables", _
        vbExclamation, "Import Word Table"
    ElseIf tableNo > 1 Then
        tableNo = InputBox("This Word document contains " & tableNo & " tables." & vbCrLf & _
        "Enter the table to start from", "Import Word Table", "1")
    End If

    resultRow = 1

    For tableStart = 1 To tableTot
        With .Tables(tableStart)
            'copy cell contents from Word table cells to Excel cells
            For iRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
                For iCol = 1 To .Columns.Count
                    Cells(resultRow, iCol) = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.Cell(iRow, iCol).Range.Text)
                Next iCol
                resultRow = resultRow + 1
            Next iRow
        End With
        resultRow = resultRow + 1
    Next tableStart
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Seems likely related to the `Clean` function against the target cell text in Word.

Comment: So I did try deleting that out but it's really no different.

Comment: Have you tried copying the table and pasting directly to Excel? There might be a way to do it like that, let me check...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found this solution which still requires the cell-wise iteration (unfortunately the line breaks are treated as cell delimiters when Pasting directly to Excel using `Paste`, `PasteSpecial` or several of the `CommandBars.ExecuteMso` options.

Try replacing the Ascii 13 character with a `vbCrLf` (carriage return + line feed) and also replacing Ascii 7 with an empty string:

```
Dim thisText as String, newText as String
For tableStart = 1 To tableTot
    With .Tables(tableStart)
        'copy cell contents from Word table cells to Excel cells
        For iRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
            For iCol = 1 To .Columns.Count
                thisText = .Cell(iRow, iCol).Range.Text
                newText = Replace(thisText, Chr(13), vbCrLf)
                newText = Replace(newText, Chr(7), vbNullString)
                Cells(resultRow, iCol) = WorksheetFunction.Clean(newText)
            Next iCol
            resultRow = resultRow + 1
        Next iRow
    End With
    resultRow = resultRow + 1
Next tableStart
```

There may be a more elegant way to do this without looping row/column, but for now this should work.

[image]

*Actual code that I tested*

```
Sub foo2()
Dim wdApp As Object, wdDoc As Object, wdTable As Object
Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents(1)
Set wdTable = wdDoc.Tables(1)
Dim iRow As Long, iCol As Long, resultRow As Long
Dim thisText As String, newText As String
resultRow = 1

With wdTable
    For iRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
        For iCol = 1 To .Columns.Count
            thisText = .Cell(iRow, iCol).Range.Text
            newText = Replace(thisText, Chr(13), vbCrLf)
            newText = Replace(newText, Chr(7), vbNullString)
            Cells(resultRow, iCol) = newText
        Next iCol
        resultRow = resultRow + 1
    Next iRow
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks again David. I just tried your edit and nothing pasted to excel at all. Also, I updated the post with some pictures to see if that would help.

Comment: It doesn't seem possible that no data would transfer, you should debug using some breakpoints to see if the inner loop `For iCol` actually executes. I'm not sure why it wouldn't, but this edit uses your entire solution with only modification to alter the text slightly.

Comment: see revision, tested & confirmed with screenshot output.

Comment: got it. Just did that and the iCol inner loop executes without errors but there's no data being transferred over :/

Comment: That doesn't seem possible. If you examine the value of `thisText` in the Locals or immediate pane, what do you see? Put a `MsgBox Cells(resultRow, iCol)` just before the `Next iCol` also to confirm.

Comment: David - I just tried the "Actual Code That You Tested" and it works!! Thank you sir!!

Comment: OK perfect. I might've mistyped or maybe you mistyped something when transferring the other code to your function, but if the test code is working, then it's just a matter of adapting that to your solution. Cheers.

Comment: I just want to thank you again. I cannot thank you enough sir. Have a blessed day!